# d3: only two "on" possible?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, listener

Using d3.js, I have a strange issue. The following code works fine:

```
var zoomHandler = d3.behavior.zoom()
                        .scaleExtent([min, max])
                        .on("zoom", function() {
                            // do something;
                        }).on("zoomend", function() {
                            // do something;
                        });
```

But, I also want my zoomHandler to deactivate another event, so I tried to extend the code like this:

```
var zoomHandler = d3.behavior.zoom()
                        .scaleExtent([min, max])
                        .on("zoom", function() {
                            // do something;
                        }).on("zoomend", function() {
                            // do something;
                        }).on("otherEvent", null);
```

But now, at runtime, I get an exception

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

Why can I only add two listeners but not three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't with the number of events, it's the event type "otherEvent" (or whatever you're using in your code). The Zoom behavior only supports [zoom events](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior#on):

> The following types are supported:
>
> - zoomstart - at the start of a zoom gesture (e.g., touchstart).
> - zoom - when the view changes (e.g., touchmove).
> - zoomend - at the end of the current zoom gesture (e.g., touchend).